# Fourier transforms - don't understand this concept!!! Please help me on this

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have two Fourier transforms to solve, but the problem is that a I have a characteristic bijection or some etching that I don't know what it is and I don't know how to solve this... Please help

$$f(x)=e^{-x}\chi_{[0,\alpha]}(x)$$

$$g=(1-|x|)\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)$$

Comment: I have edited your $\LaTeX$. I hope it is correct.

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

For any function $f$, the Fourier Transform of $f$ is
$$
\mathscr{F}f(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
and
$$
\chi_{[a,b]}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
1&\quad\text{if }a\le x\le b\\
0&\quad\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
$$
Thus, for the functions in your question,
$$
\mathscr{F}f(\xi)=\int_0^\alpha e^{-x}\,e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
and
$$
\mathscr{F}g(\xi)=\int_{-1}^1(1-|x|)\,e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: So what you mean is that the characteristic only restrict the set of the integer...

Comment: Can you tell me the results of the both of them?

Comment: My results were to the first one $$\frac{-1}{1+i\xi}$$ and the second $$\frac{4}{\theta}sin(\theta)$$

Comment: I already checked the results and corrected it!

Comment: @Amccds: It also seems you are using an alternate definition of the transform (which is perfectly fine)